# Blazor wasm self hosted - Azure App Service - Clear Cache

Tags: c#, azure, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm Self Hosted published on Azure App Service.

I'm having trouble with cache.

For example, I have a page that I changed the HTML and it´s not reflecting to the customer. He needs to open on a anonymous tab to see the changes.

I know that I can open the browser with F12 and clear the cache manually but it´s not the ideal because I have a lot of customers using the system and it has changes at least once a week.

Is there a way to force the clear cache? Can be on azure portal or programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to cache the files, then set the  `BlazorCacheBootResources` to `false`.

Add the below line in Client `.csproj` file.

```cs
<BlazorCacheBootResources>false</BlazorCacheBootResources>
```

Same is mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

> `BlazorCacheBootResources`  disables Blazor's default behavior of caching the `.dll`, `.wasm`, and other files

- Iam able to see the updated changes in razor as well as in  `index.html` static file.
- Instead of updating the code in VS and publishing again. If you want to make any changes in static files (html), update from the KUDU console.

[image]

- Restart the Application and check the updated content.
- In `KUDU` Console, `site` => `wwwroot` => `wwwroot` => `_framework`, we can see a `blazor.boot.json` file.
  It contains the `cacheBootResources` option.

[image]

- By default, the option is true, we can set to `false` in the particular `index.html`  startup file.
- In `Azure portal`, we have another option to disable the cache of the `Azure App Service`  by setting the [WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache#configure-local-cache-by-using-the-azure-portal) to `Never`.

Please refer [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68421000/19648279), which uses the  `caches.delete`, add this script in the `index.html` file.